# Background color of rows group based on value first column cells

Tags: excel, vba

basically i'm trying to sort and group by color a bunch of rows with a macro
[image: from to]

i've managed to sort the rows but i can't find a way to "group" ,or probably better "to select",
the rows by the first cell value so i can change the background color

i dont' think is useful but i put the code so far

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$G$100"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight14"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("StaffHours (5)").ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("StaffHours (5)").ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[StaffName]]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("StaffHours (5)").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How is the color value determined?  Is there a 1-to-1 table of StaffName to Color? or is there a series of Color values to be applied to the first n-unique names, and then repeated thereafter(more names than colors)? or some other rule?  Color only the first set of names, and reset the remainder of the table to some other color?

Comment: There is not really a specific rule ... I'ts just for presentation purpose ... the first approach i had was to isolate the unique values to a different colomn , assign a random color and then apply that color to all the instances .. but i couldn't get it to work ... so no , no specific rule is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could do it:

```vb
Sub ColorRows()
    
    Dim lst As ListObject, c As Range, rw As ListRow, staff, indx As Long
    Dim arrColors, dict As Object, clrIndex As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set lst = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("StaffHours (5)").ListObjects("Table1")
    indx = lst.ListColumns("StaffName").Index 'the position of the Staffname column
    arrColors = Array(vbRed, vbYellow, vbBlue, vbGreen, vbMagenta) 'or whatever you like...
    
    For Each rw In lst.ListRows          'loop over all the list rows
        With rw.Range                    'look at the Range for each row
            staff = .Cells(indx).Value   'get the staff name
            If Not dict.exists(staff) Then 'new name?  Store name and next color
                'find the index into the colors array...
                clrIndex = dict.Count Mod (UBound(arrColors) + 1) 'mod loops if more values than colors
                Debug.Print staff, clrIndex
                dict.Add staff, arrColors(clrIndex) 'store the staffname and the color
            End If
            .Interior.Color = dict(staff) 'apply the color
        End With
    Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked . Thank you very much .. Now I just want to understand exactly how the code works . I think it's gonna take me some time. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Added a few more comments, and here's an overview of the Dictionary object: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/    This is a useful component to know if you're doing any amount of VBA and working with data.

Comment: I've gave a good look to dictionary and i've upgrade my code .. but now i got stuck again .. in case you have time to llok at this my other issue  [other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71365275/exel-macro-difference-between-actual-value-and-debug-print-output) i will appreciate